# How does Visual Studio 2022 handle double-to-long long out-of-range conversion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point, visual-studio-2022

Consider the following code in C++, compiled with Visual Studio 2022:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <intrin.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << _cvt_dtoll_sent(1e31) << "\n";
    std::cout << _cvt_dtoll_sat(1e31) << "\n";
    std::cout << _cvt_dtoll_fast(1e31) << "\n";
    std::cout << (long long)1e31 << "\n";
}
```

In x86 it prints:

```
-9223372036854775808
9223372036854775807
4016683251292700672
-4571153621781053440
```

In x64 it prints:

```
-9223372036854775808
9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
-4571153621781053440
```

The program uses four different ways to convert `double` to `long long`. As `1e31` does not fit into `long long` (signed 64-bit integer), the behavior is undefined under C++ standard. However, VS2022 has [a special option that defaults to `/fpcvt:BC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fpcvt?view=msvc-170), quoting:

> The /fpcvt:BC option also makes conversion to signed types return the minimum possible value when the source is invalid

So I'd expect `(long long)1e31` to return a sentinel value of `-9223372036854775808`, just like `_cvt_dtoll_sent`. However, not only it does not return the sentinel, it does not coincide with either "saturated" or "fast" version of the conversion. Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly providing `/fpcvt:BC`?  The `_cvt_dtoll_fast` is out of range, so effectively has undefined behavior (*invalid conversions can generate different values or exceptions*), or implementation defined *unreliable behavior* if you prefer.

Comment: @Eljay I did, no difference whatsoever: non-intrinsic casts still do something completely different.

Comment: I would imagine that the "cast" version is 'resolved' (for want of a better word) at compile time; the other three force use of the intrinsic functions, which are responsive to the platform and flags.

Comment: ... yeah: *warning C4056: overflow in floating-point constant arithmetic*

Comment: Interesting, I got different behavior with `(long long)1e31` than my own tiny function `to_long_long(1e31)` which does `auto to_long_long(double x) -> long long { return static_cast<long long>(x); }`.  Compile time undefined behavior *versus*  run time undefined behavior.  (Well, *ostensibly* implementation defined behavior, as an extension.  Unless you've found a *bona fide* compiler bug and/or documentation bug!)